# Sharepoint look up - big number of lookups, so I want to write them down instead of having cascade down option

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column

I am creating a SharePoint lookup function for all the products of my company (there are a lot).

I want to, as soon as I put the code of the product, have a lot of parameters appearing.

Currently, my problem is: when I create a lookup, I have a cascade down option to select the value I want to lookup. As I have over 1K products, it takes a lot of time to search for the correct value in all the cascade down options.

An easy solution would be if I could write the value I want to look up, instead of searching and selecting it.

Is it possible, in SharePoint, to have a lookup where I can write the product code, instead of having a cascade down option, and having to go through the 1K options to find the one I want?

Thanks a lot,

Miguel

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a lookup column with a large list. You can use JSLink to create a UI control to provide a search box for users.

Check the Reference here: https://ravisoftltd.wordpress.com/2014/05/05/convert-lookup-field-to-token-input-with-jslink/

https://www.eliostruyf.com/how-to-retrieve-a-lookup-field-value-js-link/